# SEO website reviews

Tags: discussion, seo

[Example](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2584/seo-website-comparison-why-is-this-site-so-good)

I'm not sure if these are real questions. It sounds more like people seeking free labor especially for a possibly subjective issue. Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If ever there was a use for `not a real question`, this was it. I've already closed it since it is basically impossible to answer (as asked) within the confines of Q&A in a reasonable amount of time.

This is identical to the `show me teh codez` or `homework` questions that we see so often on SO. While I realize that this is *not* Stack Overflow, the down votes on this question tell me that the same sentiment applies as far as how the community views these types of questions.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with that, and that these questions are not something that are valuable for future visitors.

This kind of question was clearly seen as off-topic in the "White Hat SEO" definition phase

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1/white-hat-seo/448#448

but I guess it never came up in Pro Webmasters (I didn't initially follow Pro Webmasters, but I can't find any references).